# Maxent and GEBCO incompatibility

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ascii, maxent

I downloaded [GEBCO](http://www.gebco.net/) bathymetry data and trimmed all my environmental data with ArcGIS according to my GEBCO mask, but Maxent can't run when I insert the GEBCO data. When I delete it and only run it with my environmental layers it seems to work fine. I have already checked that GEBCO data is in .asc form using ArcGIS and this seems to work, but Maxent does not run.

---

This is the error which appears:

> For input string No data Value

Comment: Is MaxEnt giving any errors? Mind that to run MaxEnt all environmental data must have the exactly same extent, cell size and coordinate system.

Comment: this is the error the appears: For imput string No data Value

Comment: Try "reconvert" the raster again to .asc file in ArcGIS, also try set NODATA value to some numeric value (e.g. -9999). Can you post some raster info?( `gdalinfo` If you are familiar with `gdal`)

Comment: By reclasifying in the Spatyal Analyst tools in ArcGis it should work. I will try this! Thank you